# Is Tensorflow's QueueRunner Deterministic?

Tags: tensorflow

See title. Given its asynchronous properties when using more than 1 thread in the queue-runner, is the result deterministic?
Is the order of QueueRunner's produce guaranteed to be in the same order with every repeat of the program, given identical inputs to the queue?

Comment: Not deterministic. Imagine queue runner associated with tf.batch, threads race to fill the buffer so the order depends on which thread finished first

Comment: Thanks. Would you think I have a chance suggesting a feature request on github? I would think it would be possible if the threads would run concurrently and fill the buffer in deterministic order only when they are all joined (done), and then receiving the next in line - in order.

Comment: You could implement a custom queue runner uses synchronization to fill batches in deterministic order. I don't see it being very popular -- synchronization makes things slow, and there are already too many sources of non-determinism. For instance, reduce_sum on GPU is non-deterministic. Also [this](http://blog.nag.com/2011/02/wandering-precision.html)